# Losing Query String Parameters Due to truncation around &

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, get

I'm trying to use a GET to retrieve data from a Database. However when sending multiple values the query string is truncated so I only see the first. i.e. sending somepage.com/file.php?val1=v1&val2=v2 and then using $SERVER['QUERY STRING'] results in "val1=v1&" so the second parameter is lost.

Heres the important parts of code

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(degreecourse, interest, gradyear)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('GET',"/getcandidates.php?degreecourse="+ encodeURIComponent(degreecourse) + "&interest=" + encodeURIComponent(interest) + "&gradyear=" + encodeURIComponent(gradyear), false);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 || xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
     else {
              document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="Error";
          }
  }
     xmlhttp.send();
return false;   }
```

PHP

```
$degreecourse=$_GET['degreecourse'];
$interest=$_GET['interest'];
$gradyear=$_GET['gradyear'];
$fullstring = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

echo $fullstring."\n";
echo "Args = Degree - ".$degreecourse." Interest - ".$interest." Year - ".$gradyear."\n";
```

OUTPUT

```
degreecourse=Computer%20Science&
Args = Degree - Computer Science Interest - Year -
```

I've tried using encodeURIComponent over the &s but that results in the $GETs not breaking up the string correctly so you end up with something like this.

```
degreecourse=Biomedical%20Sciences%26%23038%3Binterest%3DAny%26%23038%3Bgradyear%3D2013
Args = Degree - Biomedical Sciences&interest=Any&gradyear=2013 Interest - Year -
```

Comment: You must always escape text before concatenating.

Comment: So how should i format my query string in the javascript?

Comment: How are you looking at the output?

Comment: It looks like something is HTML-encoding your text in the middle.

Comment: the output is echod back onto the requesting page and displayed.

Comment: encodeURIComponet is being used to encode the params

Comment: What do you see in the network tab in the dev tools?  What JS do you see in View Source? Something is messing up your HTTP request.

Comment: I see Query String Parameters degreecourse=Computer%20Science&
URL fragment
#:038;interest=Any&#038;gradyear=2013 cant see any JS

Comment: What JS do you see in View Source?

Comment: i see the exact same script as is shown in the question

Comment: I have Fixed the problem by using &amp; rather than &.